# Odoo dynamic Subdomain same database

Tags: python, web-services, odoo, odoo-14

In the past, I developed on ruby rails framework

on ruby, I was able to create a dynamic subdomain using routs

for ex :

If I have an app on the domain https://appdomain.com

I was able to create a subdomain for every user dynamic

ex: https://username.appdomain.com

this Subdomain was linked for example to https://appdomain.com/users/username

but it opens and shows as  >>  https://username.appdomain.com

How to make this possible in Odoo?